# Samsung Fridge displaying wrong temperature

Tags: refrigerator, cooling, freezing

I have a **Samsung RL42HGSW**, which I had replaced a faulty thermistor 8 months ago. It worked fine until these days, until another problem appeared: it displays the wrong temperature in the LED panel, however, if I **unplug and plug it again**, it shows the correct actual temperature, and, it starts to cool down to the temperature I've set (3C)(37.4F). Today, I've left it to work and see what's going to happen without replugging and it started working though you can see condensation on inner walls of the fridge denoting that temp is much more than displayed. When it started working, I replugged the fridge then saw temperature 12C (53.6F) of fridge and 4C (39.2F) of freezer. Freezer's temperature set is -20C (-4F).

Just giving a restart, unplug and plug, it fixes the problem for a day, then it returns again. What could be the issue this time? Probably defrosting issues (but I don't think because it is actually able to cool down, just doesn't know *when* to cool)? Or anything else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really home improvement and would be better answered on small appliance repair.

Comment: Are you sure the thermostat is not getting covered with ice? 1 day is fairly quick but in a freezer ice is an insulator , I am thinking that power cycle is restarting the timers and gets things working until it freezes over again.

Comment: @EdBeal where can I find the thermostat location for this model to not disassemble it fully, any idea? Also, today I just re-set the temp (originally was 3C, set to 1C then back to 3C) and it started working again, can hear the fridge working. If it cools down, then I don't think ice is an issue here?

Comment: You mentioned replacing the thermistor that is the sensor the small solid material if in contact with the evaporator coil may be freezing it I am not sure but you mentioned a temp shift when replacing this could be because of the location possibly in contact with a coil or fin when there should be a small air gap , although the shift could be because a slightly different resistance from the original.

Comment: @EdBeal Aha, so it may be wrongly placed? I did not replace it myself, a technician did it a lot of months ago. But if that would be the case, why replugging would make it work again if it's freezed? I'm suspecting more of electronic board or something. I guess I should contact the technician again?

Comment: I am just guessing a restart cycle may defrost it. But I have adjusted the sensors to shift the operating temp on air conditioners.

Comment: Use the dollar bill trick and test the door gaskets. It sounds like you are icing up and losing capacity. I would post this in the appliance section and include make and model of the unit.